# JTabbedPane not showing other tabs added

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have been looking around about JTabbedPane's and can't seem to find any solution.

I am using GridBagLayout as the manager as I am more comfortable with this (I am new to Java programming).

I have made the the class, and extended it with JPanel, and adding all the classes on another class, when i run program all i see is blank screen, i will post code so you can see.

(Test Class / GUI Class)

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class test1 extends JPanel {

    JTextField ID, Name, Address1, Address2,
            Post_Code, Landline, Mobile, Card_Name,
            Card_Number, Expiry_Date, Security_Number,
            Identification = new JTextField();
    ResultSet rs1;
    Connection conn;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    //JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    String items[] = {"Yes", "No"};
    JComboBox box = new JComboBox(items);

    public test1() {
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        c1.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 0;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        jp2.add(new JLabel("Customer Registration"), c1);
        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 1;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        jp2.add(new JLabel("ID"), c1);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 1;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        jp2.add(ID = new JTextField(10), c1);
        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 2;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        jp2.add(new JLabel("Name"), c1);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 2;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        jp2.add(Name = new JTextField(10), c1);
        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 3;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        jp2.add(new JLabel("Address"), c1);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 3;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        jp2.add(Address1 = new JTextField(15), c1);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 4;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        jp2.add(Address2 = new JTextField(15), c1);
        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 5;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        jp2.add(new JLabel("Post Code"), c1);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 5;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        jp2.add(Post_Code = new JTextField(10), c1);
        c1.gridx = 0;
        c1.gridy = 6;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        jp2.add(new JLabel("Landline"), c1);
        c1.gridx = 1;
        c1.gridy = 6;
        c1.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        jp2.add(Landline = new JTextField(10), c1);
    }
}
```

The class that combines all JTabbedPane's together:

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class tabadd extends JFrame {

```
JTabbedPane tab = new JTabbedPane();
Customer_Registration CR = new Customer_Registration();
test1 g = new test1();

public tabadd() {
    tab.add("Customer Registration", CR);
    tab.add("Equipment Registration", g);
    getContentPane().add(tab);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            tabadd m = new tabadd();
            m.setTitle("Test");
            m.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            m.setSize(1280, 720);
            m.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            m.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

}

there will be multiple classes hence the Customer_Registration class.

Once again thanks for all your help.

Comment: or better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have tested your code and I find no problem. Instead of a Customer_Registration, I'm sending null and I can see the tabs, so maybe your problem is in the object CR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not adding the jp2 panel anywhere. Add the following line at the end of the `test1` class constructor.

```
add(jp2);
```

Another choice is to have the `GridBagLayout` set as the layout manager to the `test1` `JPanel` and add all the components directly to it. This way you avoid using an extra `jp2` panel.

And please use the standard Java naming for classes, such as `test1` becomes `Test1`.

Comment: Dan ty for the response it worked :), how stupid of me to forget that LOL